# Php LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7 not tracing

Tags: php, logging, ldap

I'm trying to get ldap_bind to trace out what its doing.  I have the following

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ds = ldap_connect($server);
$r = ldap_bind($ds, $admin, $passwd);
```

I removed some code setting up variables.  However I want to see the trace statements to help trouble shoot another issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to print out the errors using `ldap_error($ds)` after setting the option `ldap_set_option`. The following link http://ourlife01.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/debugging-ldap-php-scripts.html has an example.