# connect to ldap secure google from php gives error Unable to start TLS

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to connect to google.ldap.com in php 7.3 but I get an error: "Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error"

my code:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap.google.com');
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE, "Google_xxxxx.crt");
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_KEYFILE, "Google_xxxxx.key");
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_start_tls($ldap);
```

my cert file and key file are both located in the same folder.

I'm using Xampp on a windows 10 machine.

I have tried to change:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap.google.com');
```

into

```
$ldap = ldap_connect('ldaps://ldap.google.com',636);
```

but I still get the same error.

If somebody knows what is wrong with the code, thanks!

Comment: Only the single parameter version should be used, and it should include the port if non-standard, so `ldaps://ldap.google.com:636`. Make sure to test the return value of `ldap_connect`. You should be able to get deeper error info using this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587210/231316

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work.  Maybe somebody has a working code to use google ldap secure on a windows pc using Xampp.  Perhaps it has something to do with certificates that are not loading(?)

Comment: I solved it myself.  Remove ldap_start_tls($ldap) from the code.  Use lldap_connect('ldaps://ldap.google.com:636') what Chris mentioned above.  And add the path before the certificates LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE, "c:\xxx\Google_xxxxx.crt");